# python threading with lock gives identical values

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Here is an interesting code although not very practical since it's better to use thread local, but I used this to learn about locks.

```
import threading
import thread
import time
import random
count = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

def increment(num):
    global count
    with lock:
        count += num
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 1.5))
    with lock:
        print "t1: %f" % count

def decrement(num):
    global count
    with lock:
        count -= num
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 2.5))
    with lock:
        print "t2: %f" % count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = []
    for i in range(5):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=(random.random(),))
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=decrement, args=(random.random(),))
        t1.start(); t2.start()
        threads.append(t1);threads.append(t2);

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print "Done"
```

The question is why does it print identical numbers?
If I use a single lock in the method like:

```
def increment(num):
    global count
    with lock:
        count += num
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 1.5))
        print "t1: %f" % count
```

then it works as expected printing random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of the time, when thread go to `sleep`, the CPU switch the context to other thread.
so, in your code, both threads reach the second `with lock` block after both of them already finished the first `with lock` block (i.e. after both of them change `count` value).
so `count` does not change anymore and contains a specific value when they reach the second lock block and print `count` value. (after both `increment` and `decrement` finish the first `with lock` block).

change it to this if you want to see differences:

```
def increment(num):
    global count
    with lock:
        count += num
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 1.5))
        print "t1: %f" % count

def decrement(num):
    global count
    with lock:
        count -= num
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 2.5))
        print "t2: %f" % count
```

(you can also delete the `sleep` commands)

Comment: That would justify it. I did not think it would since the sleep command is in the time package rather than the threading package. Also I was just playing around with this; For those who want to use this code, you would not need any sleep command. cheers

Comment: @max I didn't understand what you are trying to say.